# How to find partial matches in a list of strings when modifying a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame 'df':

```
        id value
0      ABC    hi
1      XYZ   hey
```

that I want to compare to a list of strings 'str_list':

```
str_list = ['abc_123', 'xyz_456']
```

to find partial matches to then replace the value if the partial match on 'id' is found in the str_list to make something like this:

```
        id       value
0      ABC   new_value
1      XYZ   new_value
```

As of now I have this code:

```
df.loc[df['id'].isin(str_list), 'value'] = 'new_val'
```

but that only works on complete matches (so the df 'id' values would have to be abc_123,xyz_456) in ordre to see the new_vals added.

How can I modify this to accept partial matches?

```
import pandas as pd
str_list = ['abc_123', 'xyz_456']
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['ABC','XYZ'], 'value':['hi','hey']})
# this commented out df will trigger the matches correctly
#df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['abc_123','xyz_456'], 'value':['hi','hey']})
print(df)
df.loc[df['id'].isin(str_list), 'value'] = 'new_val'
print(df)
```

Comment: Please accept as solution by clicking the checkmark next to the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some list comprehension for this task to see if a `lower()` of your dataframe value is in the list.

```
import pandas as pd
str_list = ['abc_123', 'xyz_456']
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['ABC','XYZ'], 'value':['hi','hey']})
```

---

```
df['match'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: min([y for y in str_list if x.lower() in y]))
df

Out[1]: 
    id value    match
0  ABC    hi  abc_123
1  XYZ   hey  xyz_456
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Create new dataframe

 df2=pd.DataFrame({'text':str_list})

#Compute df['value'] using map by creating a dict from new datframe

df['value']=df.id.map(dict(zip(df2['text'].str.upper().str.split('_').str[0],df2['text'])))


   id    value
0  ABC  abc_123
1  XYZ  xyz_456
```

**How it works**

```
    #new dataframe
        df2=pd.DataFrame({'text':str_list})
    # new column in new dataframe
         df2['new']=df2['text'].str.upper().str.split('_').str[0]
    #dict of the two columns in new datframe
    d=dict(zip(df2['text'].str.upper().str.split('_').str[0],df2['text']))
    #map dict to initial dataframe
    df['value']=df['id'].map(d)
```